Why is Outlook Add-In Mobile Button Not Appearing
I am developing an add-in for outlook using an xml manifest. On outlook classic, and outlook on the web I my add-in works properly. I am testing my add-in by sideloading it through @microsft/teamsapp-cli.
Here is the manifest I'm uploading (some info has been ommited as it was flagging the spam filter)
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <MobileFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                  <Label resid="MobileGroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="msgMobileReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="MobileTaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                      <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.25" scale="1"/>
                      <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.25" scale="2"/>
                      <bt:Image size="25" resid="Icon.25" scale="3"/>

                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32" scale="1"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32" scale="2"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32" scale="3"/>

                      <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.48" scale="1"/>
                      <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.48" scale="2"/>
                      <bt:Image size="48" resid="Icon.48" scale="3"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Mobile.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.25" DefaultValue="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/43/25/25.jpg?hmac=dFVPi1N66hF5Nu6Vht9R8v2pTFSKhmKU_lfJyN6N71U"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32" DefaultValue="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/368/32/32.jpg?hmac=ucn_73IpWzjLir7leRkH-0jusJfW9YqLv1ENDeOWn0s"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.48" DefaultValue="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/721/48/48.jpg?hmac=6cgH6IJ4VNV5o9QruHjE2lqNeYejgPCzBIKbgYOo90M"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="task-pane.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Mobile.Url" DefaultValue=""task-pane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Simple Form Test"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show DN"/>
          <bt:String id="MobileGroupLabel" DefaultValue="Simple Form Test"/>
          <bt:String id="MobileTaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Form"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>

In Mobile, it simply does not show up when I open the context menu where it should be. I'm stuck as outlook gives no feedback on what is actually happening behind the scenes and I believe that I am following all Microsoft specs.
